# Прототипы - присваивание свойства

Tags: javascript, dom, объекты, prototype, property

Есть задача: при отсутствии textContent'а - перенять принцип работы innerText'а.

Вот правильное решение:

```
  if (document.documentElement.textContent === undefined) {


    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "textContent", {
      get: function() {
        return this.innerText;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this.innerText = value;
      }
    });
  }
```

Но меня не столько интересует верный ответ, сколько то, почему вот этот код:

```
if (HTMLElement.prototype.textContent === undefined) {
   HTMLElement.prototype.textContent = HTMLElement.prototype.innerText;
}
```

... не сработает.

Меня интересует:

1. Что находится внутри innerText'а? Точно такие же геттеры-сеттеры,
   как и в правильном решении?
2. Если в innerText'е находится такой же
   объект с геттер-сеттером, то почему операция присваивания, не делает
   из .textContent'а - обычную ссылку на тот объект?
3. Или проблема в контексте this'ов?

Кто знает - объясните всю подноготную происходящего.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, почему решили *стандартное* свойство `textContent` реализовывать через <strike>***не** стандартный*</strike> стандартный с 2016 г. [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).

`innerText` это **свойство**, в данном случае оно представлено в виде двух функции: getter и setter.

При обращении к свойству - происходит **вычисление** нужной функции, поэтому нельзя *позаимствовать* свойство целиком, как обычную функцию.

В этом случае

```
HTMLElement.prototype.innerText;
```

Происходит попытка получить **значение** `innerText`, и так как `HTMLElement.prototype` не является элементом, кидается исключение.

---

В *правильном* решении, добавляется новое свойство, *внутри*, которого вызывает уже имеющееся свойство, так как в момент вызова `this` уже существующий элемент все работает.

Альтернативным решением может быть копирование определения свойства, для этого можно получить `property descriptor`, с помощью [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

И затем добавить его же, но уже с нужным именем:

```
var innerTextPropertyDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype,'innerText');
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "textContent", innerTextPropertyDescriptor);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Что находится внутри innerText'а? Точно такие же геттеры-сеттеры

Да.

> почему операция присваивания, не делает из .textContent'а - обычную ссылку на тот объект?

Потому что при присваивании для левой части вызывается сеттер (или создаётся свойство), а для правой - геттер. Соответственно, ты присваиваешь значение, возвращённое геттером, а не сам геттер.

> Или проблема в контексте this'ов?

Нет.

> Вот правильное решение

Нет.

[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) - IE9+ и все остальные
[`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) - IE6+ и все кроме FF45-
[`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) - IE9+ (IE8 с оговорками) и все остальные

Получается, что даже в идеальном случае это решение покрывает единстыенный браузер IE8 (и то, надо это проверять, причём, желательно, в самом браузере, а не в эмуляции).

И это не говоря о том, что эти свойства не являются взаимозаменяемыми, из-за чего в jQuery не стали так делать. Вот, запусти это в хроме:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div")

console.log(JSON.stringify(div.textContent))
console.log(JSON.stringify(div.innerText))
```

```html
<div>
  <span>123</span>
  <script>var any = {}</script>
</div>
```

Comment: `Или проблема в контексте this'ов?`
`Нет.`
Насколько я понял, то проблема именно в них. При присваивании вызовется геттер innerText'а - а внутри у его "return this.data" (образно говоря, ведь я не знаю что там внутри), и это "this" обратится к HTML.prototype, как написал @Grundy, поэтому у элемента создастся свойство textContent, в котором будет скорее всего undefined.

Comment: @1px_solid_black, нет, проблема не в `this` а в том, что это свойство. То есть это не функция, ссылку на которую можно взять и присвоить в другой объект. При обращении к свойству эта функция сразу вызывается, и даже если бы исключение не кидалось - ты получил бы **значение**, которое вернула функция, а не саму функцию

Comment: @Grundy, если бы в свойстве innerText, представим себе, не было бы get-set'ов, тогда присваивание бы сработало, и textContent - стал бы ссылкой на свойство innerText?
`ты получил бы значение, которое вернула функция, а не саму функцию`
и этим значением было бы undefined (от HTMLElement.prototype) - так?

Comment: @Grundy или без get-set'ов, innerText стало бы обычным примитивом?

Comment: @1px_solid_black, не примитивом, а обычным полем.

Answer (score 0):

Да, свойство `innerText` имеет геттер (можно в этом убедится в консоли браузера), поэтому для вычисления результата, который нужно присвоить свойству `textContent`, он будет вызван. Поскольку геттер вызывается при этом не как метод объекта, а просто функция, то значением `this` внутри геттера будет `undefined`. В реализации геттера по всей видимости (если я правильно понимаю, это зашито в движке браузера) присутствует проверка на этот случай и результатом будет ошибка `TypeError: 'get innerText' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.`